# Single fragment to load multiple layout android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to make a quiz application for android,where each page will have a single question and on click of next button second question will be displayed,
I want to keep the next button common and use single fragment to display different layouts on click of next button.And on the basis of answer submitted next question will be displayed.
How to achieve this.How to use single fragment for multiple layout and maintain its stack.

Comment: Welcome to SO. In order to get helpful answers you should post the code you have tried so far!

Comment: I have implemented with multiple fragments and replaced the fragment each time on click of next button.I want to do it will single fragment but not able to achieve.Not able to proceed

Comment: Again, show us your code. You may edit your question at any time to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Using different layouts to load various questions would be an incorrect solution to your problem, rather fetch the data from your question bank(xml, excel, db, any source) and set your question TextView to it. The Multiple choice answers(if any) could also be populated in the same way on a single fragment. You would just need one single layout.